# Help with storing JSON data

Tags: apex, json, parsing

I'm new to salesforce and I have to parse [this](https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=) JSON and store the values in variables. I have used json2apex which generated 2 classes for me. When I use system.debug I can see it's reading the JSON object, however I have no idea how to store this many variables it in List<> format I used this line to store them but it does not work:
for(Meals m: retrievedMeals){
mealData.add(m.meals[]);
}

Can somebody please give me help me to store these values?

```
public class Meals {
@AuraEnabled
public List<Meals> meals;

@AuraEnabled
public String idMeal;
@AuraEnabled
public String strMeal;
@AuraEnabled
public String strCategory;
@AuraEnabled
public String strArea;
@AuraEnabled
public String strInstructions;
@AuraEnabled
public String strMealThumb;

public static Meals parse(String json) {
return (Meals) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Meals.class);
    }
}


public with sharing class MealsRetriever {
private static final String MEAL_URL = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=';
private static final String GET = 'GET';

public static List<Meals> getMealData(){

    List<Meals> mealData = new List<Meals>();

    Http httpCallout = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(MEAL_URL);
    req.setMethod(GET);

    HttpResponse mealResponse = httpCallout.send(req);
    Meals mealParseResponse = Meals.parse(mealResponse.getBody());
    List<Meals> retrievedMeals = mealParseResponse.meals;
    
    /*this is the part where i try to store the values, but I dont know how
    for(Meals m: retrievedMeals){
       //Meals.idMeals = retrievedMeals.get('idMeal');
    }


    return mealData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have read that, however I still can't figure it out how to store the values in a List<>

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish but it doesn't sound like it's related to parsing JSON. Suggest modifying your question and describing your objectives. Perhaps [Intro to Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro) Trailhead would be useful to you. Also, inlining your code in the question rather than linking to Pastebin is a little friendlier for readers.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't quite make sense, but I *think* what you are seeking to do is iterate over a list of deserialized JSON objects and collect the values of a specific property.

First of all, this declaration does not belong in your `Meals` class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public List<Meals> meals;
```

This data structure is not self-referential (it does not contain instances of itself), and the data point you are seeking to retrieve is a `String`. You therefore need a *local* variable typed as a `List<String>`.

You probably want something like this:

```
List<Meals> retrievedMeals = mealParseResponse.meals;
List<String> mealIds = new List<String>();
for (Meals m : retrievedMeals) {
    mealIds.add(m.idMeal);
}
```

The `get()` method is available only on sObjects, not Objects like this one.

---

Alternately, if what you're really trying to do is return a list of Meal records, the most natural way to parse this is to use two classes to represent the inner and outer structures:

```
public class Meals {
    public class Meal {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String idMeal;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String strMeal;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String strCategory;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String strArea;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String strInstructions;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String strMealThumb;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Meal> meals;


    public static Meals parse(String json) {
        return (Meals) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Meals.class);
    }
}
```

Then, you can return a `List<Meals.Meal>` derived from the top-level key `meals` (note that `Meal` is an inner class here):

```
    HttpResponse mealResponse = httpCallout.send(req);
    Meals mealParseResponse = Meals.parse(mealResponse.getBody());
    return Meals.meals;
```

Comment: Hello David, thanks a lot for your reply. After your answer I now have the following code:
Meals mealParseResponse = Meals.parse(mealResponse.getBody());
        List<Meals> retrievedMeals = mealParseResponse.meals;
        List<String> mealIds = new List<String>();
        for (Meals m : retrievedMeals) {
            mealIds.add(m.idMeal);
        }
But the .parse() say 'incorrect signature: void parse(String) from the type List<Meals>'
And also cant find the variable 'meals' but I declared it: 'List<Meals> meals = new List<Meals>();'
Can you help me please?

Comment: `List<Meals>` does not have a `parse()` method. `Meals` does. `Meals` has a property `meals`, typed as a `List<Meals.Meal>`, not a `List<Meals>`. Assuming you're doing something like what I proposed above.